# How to change rootViewController's view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    CustomView1 *CustomView = [[CustomView1 alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController.view = CustomView;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

This appears in AppDelegate.m

I want to change `rootViewcontroller`'s view to `CustomView`, and tried the code above, but the background color remained black and touch event weren't accepted.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where the fault is but I have 2 suggestions.

1) Change

```
CustomView1 *CustomView = [[CustomView1 alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController.view = CustomView;
```

to

```
CustomView1 *CustomView = [[CustomView1 alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:CustomView];
```

or

2) In both you .xib files referenced go to the top view and change it to use a custom class.  Then you can just let the app launch like normal

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

[image]

Side note:
You should avoid naming variables that begin with uppercase letters.  Many coding standards have classes begin with uppercase letters and variables begin with lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need two different view controllers to manage one view class, you should make the view controllers load the right view class in their `loadView` method or in their nib file. I guess the controllers in your code use nibs. If so, edit the nibs to set the view class to `CustomView1`.

`CustomView1` is an unfortunate choice of class name, IMHO, because it doesn't mean anything.